# Programaticallly re-organising pandas slices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-munging

*Edit for clarity*

I have a set of dataframes that I need to combine programatically. Each one represents a particular participant over a set of treatment sessions. Each frame comes from 1 sheet of an excel workbook (one workbook per client, 1 worksheet per psychometric instrument) which I have imported into pandas.

The data frame below is an example of Participant a, instrument a:

```
|           | beaseline     | time 1    | time 1 change     | time 1 change from baseline   | time 2    | time 2 change     | time 2 change from baseline   |
|---------  |-----------    |--------   |---------------    |-----------------------------  |--------   |---------------    |-----------------------------  |
| item 1    | 3             | 4         | Nan               | 1                             | 4         | 0                 | 1                             |
| item 2    | 3             | 2         | Nan               | 0                             | 3         | 1                 | 0                             |
| item 3    | 1             | 1         | Nan               | 0                             | 2         | 1                 | 1                             |
| item 4    | 1             | 1         | Nan               | 0                             | 1         | 0                 | 0                             |
| item 5    | 1             | 2         | Nan               | 1                             | 1         | -1                | 0                             |
```

I need to combine this with observations from other participants in a tabular dataframe such that each row is a participant and each column is a reponse to an item *at a particular time point*.*

So I need to reshaped this data into something like this:

```
|       | Baseline item 1   | Baseline item 2   | Baseline item 3   | Baseline item 4   | Baseline item 5   | time 1 item 1     | time 1 item 2     |
|---    |-----------------  |-----------------  |-----------------  |-----------------  |-----------------  |---------------    |---------------    |
| 0     | 3                 | 3                 | 1                 | 1                 | 1                 | 4                 | 2                 |
```

Once I have done this reshaping for each dataframe I can then append them together and add the client code as the first column, thereby distinguishing each participant.

```
|       | Client code   | Baseline item 1   | Baseline item 2   | Baseline item 3   | Baseline item 4   | Baseline item 5   | time 1 item 1     | time 1 item 2     |
|---    |-------------  |-----------------  |-----------------  |-----------------  |-----------------  |-----------------  |---------------    |---------------    |
| 0     | xxi212121     | 3                 | 3                 | 1                 | 1                 | 1                 | 4                 | 2                 |               | 4                 | 2                 |
```

I have already used a lot of repeated code and essentially manually pulled each slice as a series, renamed it and then created a new dataframe:

```
baseline = pd.Dataframe(raw_data.iloc[2:,1])
time_1 = pd.Dataframe(raw_data.iloc[2:,2])
```

but obviously this is a really silly solution.

I need to able to repeat this across a lot of similar dataframes so I need a more useful solution, Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic, and where is the data for other participants? I mean how are you going to distinguish the data from one participant with another..

Comment: I have edited the post to try to address this, however, the particular issue at hand is reshaping the data I showed in table one. When it comes to combining data I can already solve that problem. Thank you for pointing out the needed changes though.

Comment: Is  the column containing the `items`  set as index of the dataframe?

Comment: No. I have had to do some editing to eliminate empty rows and columns because of the formatting of the worksheet but I have not set the index or columns of the DF

Comment: Thanks for providing the info, just one last question..Is there any `header/col name` for the `items` column..for example in `raw_data`

Comment: While there is a header for each column I haven't yet assigned it to be the actual colname so both the row and columns are numbered rather than named. And thank you for asking the questions to clarify any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and flatten the `MultiIndex` columns, then with `np.hstack` horizontally stack all the rows in the dataframe and create a new dataframe from `stacked` rows with the flattened columns:

```
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns[1:], df.iloc[:, 0]]).map('-'.join)
s = pd.DataFrame([np.hstack(df.to_numpy()[:, 1:].T)], columns=i)
```

Example (column names removed for simplicity):

```
print(df)

        0  1  2    3  4  5  6  7
0  item 1  3  4  Nan  1  4  0  1
1  item 2  3  2  Nan  0  3  1  0
2  item 3  1  1  Nan  0  2  1  1
3  item 4  1  1  Nan  0  1  0  0
4  item 5  1  2  Nan  1  1 -1  0
```

---

```
print(s)

   1-item 1  1-item 2  1-item 3  1-item 4  1-item 5  2-item 1  2-item 2  2-item 3  2-item 4  2-item 5 3-item 1 3-item 2 3-item 3 3-item 4 3-item 5  4-item 1  4-item 2  4-item 3  4-item 4  4-item 5  5-item 1  5-item 2  5-item 3  5-item 4  5-item 5  6-item 1  6-item 2  6-item 3  6-item 4  6-item 5  7-item 1  7-item 2  7-item 3  7-item 4  7-item 5
0         3         3         1         1         1         4         2         1         1         2      Nan      Nan      Nan      Nan      Nan         1         0         0         0         1         4         3         2         1         1         0         1         1         0        -1         1         0         1         0         0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time. When I try to run this code I am getting a traceback with ```keyerror 0``` I will continue to play around with it a bit and try to make it work.

Comment: try with the quotes `'0'`...or instead in place of `df[0]`  use `df.iloc[:, 0]`

Comment: While this works it doesn't give me the output you show above. It seems to skip the first few columns (rather than just the items column).

Comment: I'm trying to run this answer on a very similar data set but I'm getting the error:

```TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found```

Any idea where this might be coming from?